# Is it possible to store data in ESP32 permanently with the address specified by me in suitable memory section?

Tags: memory-management, esp32, arduino-esp32

I can store data in the RAM with this code.

```
uint32_t * Ptr = (uint32_t*)0x3F800000;
*Ptr = 0xFF;                               // 0xFF value is stored at 0x3F800000 address location.
```

But i want to store data permanently in the flash memory without using library. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Why do you not want to use a library?

Comment: "How can I achieve this"? If you don't want to use a library, first read the section of "System and Memory" of  [ESP32 Technical Reference](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_technical_reference_manual_en.pdf), particularly the section 1.3.3, find the datasheet of the flash chip it used and see how to communicate with the chip via SPI and write your own driver. There are time that you don't want to use some bloated library, but in this case, trust me, you'd want to use a library.

Comment: @romkey I just want to learn how to play with memory from the root level.

Comment: Then you should also consider wear leveling.

Comment: Why not get an external flash part and write programs to read/write it? There are several kinds (e.g., serial flash) and it is definitely interfacing at low level.